# Problem with MaxScaleDenominator in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, sld

I'm using GeoServer version 2.7.6, and I had to publish a WMS service, I tried to establish a limit in the scale (with `<se:MaxScaleDenominator>5001.0</se:MaxScaleDenominator>`) but when I view the layer, it lets me see it on all scales without limit. That´s to say that MaxScaleDenominator is not working for me.

Please I need help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
   xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   version="1.1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld   http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
   xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>Cartografia</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>Cartografia</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Single symbol</se:Name>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>5001.0</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#8c8f8c</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>   
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: try removing the se: prefix - it's not clear to me why you are randomly mixing namespaces.